# Rails - Duplicating part of a form to submit multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails form with many fields.
A user wants to be able to duplicate a section of the form containing 6 fields by clicking a button so the 6 fields appear twice on the page, then fill in the fields and submit the form creating 2 new records.

```
= form_for @item, :html => { :class => "form-horizontal" } do |f|
    .panel
      h4 Personal Details
      .field
        = f.label :contact_name
        = f.text_field :contact_name
      .field
        = f.label :email_address
        = f.text_field :email_address

    .duplicate-section.panel
      h4 Info
      .field
        = f.label :location
        = f.select :location
      .field
        = f.label :time
        = f.text_field :time

    = link_to "Add new Info Section", '#'
```

The link_to adds a new `.duplicate-section` to the form so I can can create the extra fields on the page but I don't know how to submit the form as two separate records.

Comment: Are you trying to create 2 `Item`? or just the info section (`location` and `time`)?

Comment: 2 items with identical :name & :email but differing :location & :time

Comment: have a look at fields_for helper that you can use in rails. this works with one-to-many relation-ships and is probably what you want there.

Comment: I agree with phoet, split the location and time to a seperate model of sub_items, then you can use fields_for to build an unlimited number of sub_items and they all map directly to the single record of contact_name and email_address rather than repeating the name and email multiple times in the same table.

Answer (score 0):

To manage this, you can create a model that encapsulate your differents records:

run

```
rails g model item_wrapper
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

app/models/item_wrapper.rb

```
class ItemWrapper < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :items
end
```

And follow [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2) to create add and remove info section buttons.

finnaly you can customize javascript produced by changing fields to hidden and fill value for your items duplicated fields.

To sum up:

1. create a wrapper for your items (which contains just an id)
2. create an has_many nested form for your items inside your wrapper form (with fields_for)
3. create add_fields button (cf rails cast)
4. then customize your js add_fields function to change fields with duplicated content

Cheers

Believing that it is clear enought, I can edit the answer to be more clear on demand.